# Comparing elements in an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, compare

I have to check to see if the "tokens" in the arraylist are in increasing order.

```
private E[] data;      // where the data is stored   
private int size;      // how many items have been added to the list

public TopSpinArray(int numTokens, int spinSize)
{
    super(numTokens, spinSize);

    data = (E[])(new Object[numTokens]);
    size = 0;
} 

public boolean isSolved()
{     
    for(int i = 0; i < numTokens; i++)
    {
        if(data[i] < data[i+1])
        { 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

when I compile, it says "bad operand types for binary operator '<'
                           first type: E; second type: E"

how do I check to see if they are increasing?

Comment: Please add the declaration of 'data' - we need to know what type it is if we are to help you.

Comment: your loop will exit once first element turns out to be less than second. You need to return false once you see elements the other way around. wrt your compilation problem see atk's comment.

Comment: This is an `array`, not an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 4):

The operator `<` is only valid for certain types of objects. To be able to compare any comparable type of object (I take your `E` to imply that your tokens indeed implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), since otherwise your question makes no sense,) you can use [`compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29):

```
for(int i = 0; i < numTokens - 1; i++) {
     if(data[i].compareTo(data[i+1]) > 0) { 
         return false;
     }
}
return true;
```

Comment: @awashburn: They should be in ascending order, so if `compareTo()` returns something `> 0`, something is wrong.